# Codeigniter routes not working in sub-folders

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a application with Codeigniter
in controllers folder I have

> front/
>   admin/players/players.php

players is the folder inside /admin and player.php is my controller.

when I try to access with following url i am getting 404 error.

> http://localhost/mysite.com/admin/players/players

In routes.php i have defined

```
$route['default_controller'] = "admin/login";  
$route['admin/players'] = "admin/players/players";  
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

but its showing 404 error. can you please locate the problem?

Comment: How have you written class defination of players.php? Can you post first few lines of it? Also does players.php have players() function ?

Comment: class Players extends CI_Controller { 
 
  function __construct()
  {
         parent::__construct();
     }
}

Comment: Does it have players() function ?

Comment: i added it now and checked.but its still showing 404 error.

Comment: what happens if you simply go to: http://localhost/mysite.com/admin/players

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this your whole controller code?

```
class Players extends CI_Controller { function __construct() { parent::__construct(); } }
```

If so, you are missing an `index(){}` function

`localhost/mysite.com/admin/players` is redirecting to
`localhost/mysite.com/admin/players/players` which is essentially the same as
`localhost/mysite.com/admin/players/players/index`

Breaking down your segments, this means you need a controller "players.php" in your "/admin/players" directory, and this controller needs an "index" function.